# Adding 64 bit asm instructions to 32bit asm code

Tags: nasm

I am planning to write the smallest binary file in terms of size in binary. I am following the instructions as given [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/CSE131/teensyELF.htm). I have successfully managed to reduce the size of my binary using 32 bit asm to 64 bytes. Now I want to convert the 32 bit assembly language to 64 bit language.
This is the code that I tried:

```
; tiny.asm

  BITS 32

                org     0x00200000

                db      0x7F, "ELF"             ; e_ident
                db      1, 1, 1, 0
  _start:
                mov     bl, 42        ;These are the lines where
                xor     eax, eax      ;I want to insert the 64 bit
                inc     eax           ;instructions. 
                int     0x80          ;
                db      0
                dw      2                       ; e_type
                dw      3                       ; e_machine
                dd      1                       ; e_version
                dd      _start                  ; e_entry
                dd      phdr - $$               ; e_phoff
  phdr:         dd      1                       ; e_shoff       ; p_type
                dd      0                       ; e_flags       ; p_offset
                dd      $$                      ; e_ehsize      ; p_vaddr
                                                ; e_phentsize
                dw      1                       ; e_phnum       ; p_paddr
                dw      0                       ; e_shentsize
                dd      filesize                ; e_shnum       ; p_filesz
                                                ; e_shstrndx
                dd      filesize                                ; p_memsz
                dd      5                                       ; p_flags
                dd      0x1000                                  ; p_align

  filesize      equ     $ - $$
```

As per the code I did have some wild guesses. However, the compiler is expecting 32 bit instructions when I tried to tinker with it giving registers and syscall of 64 bit asm.

The code I used to execute the program is :

```
  $ nasm -f bin -o a.out tiny.asm
  $ chmod +x a.out
  $ ./a.out ; echo $?
  42
  $ wc -c a.out
       64 a.out
```

Any idea or any sort of lead in this will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a 64bit version of nasm?  Have you tried [google](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/)?

Comment: I was looking for crazy small binary file - and the above instructions helps me achieve that. I will be looking into the link you gave me.